# How to find match for exact word using pattern matcher in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

1. I have shared my sample code here. here i am trying to find word **"engine"** with different strings. i used word boundary to match the words in string.
2. it matches word if it starts with #engine(example).
3. it should only match with exact word.

   ```
   private void checkMatch() {
       String source1 = "search engines has ";
       String source2 = "search engine exact word";
       String source3 = "enginecheck";
       String source4 = "has hashtag #engine";
       String key = "engine";

       System.out.println(isContain(source1, key));
       System.out.println(isContain(source2, key));
       System.out.println(isContain(source3, key));
       System.out.println(isContain(source4, key));

   }

   private boolean isContain(String source, String subItem) {
       String pattern = "\\b" + subItem + "\\b";
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
       Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
       return m.find();
   }

   **Expected output**
       false
       true
       false
       false

   **actual output**
       false
       true
       false
       true
   ```

Comment: Do you only need to get true or false if the string contains a whole word `engine`? And: are you searching for literal text only?

Comment: Regex Search is not really performant for exact strings. Just remove the `\b`s (java.util.Matcher will then switch to string search), and check the boundaries to be white spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, you have to use regex OR instead of word boundary. `\\b` matches between a word char and non-word char (vice-versa). So your regex should find a match in `#engine` since `#` is a non-word character.

```
private boolean isContain(String source, String subItem) {
    String pattern = "(?m)(^|\\s)" + subItem + "(\\s|$)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
    return m.find();
}
```

or

```
String pattern = "(?<!\\S)" + subItem + "(?!\\S)";
```

Comment: its returning true for all the case @Avinash

Comment: Thank you so much @avinash  String pattern = "(?<!\\S)" + subItem + "(?!\\S)";  is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Change your pattern as below.

```
 String pattern = "\\s" + subItem + "\\b";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a literal text enclosed with spaces or start/end of the string, you can split the string with a mere whitespace pattern like `\s+` and check if any of the chunks equals the search text.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/D0zXID):

```
String s = "Can't start the #engine here, but this engine works";
String searchText = "engine";
boolean found = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+"))
       .anyMatch(word -> word.equals(searchText));
System.out.println(found); // => true
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the regexp to

```
String pattern = "\\s"+subItem + "\\s";
```

I'm using the

> \s A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]

For more info look into the [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) javadoc

Also if you want to support strings like these:

```
"has hashtag engine"
"engine"
```

You can improve it by adding the ending/starting line terminators (^ and $)
by using this pattern:

```
String pattern = "(^|\\s)"+subItem + "(\\s|$)";
```